# Allow to use only a defined set of structures values

Tags: c++, structure

I have C++ structure which should contain only a limited of values. For example:

```
struct Foo {
  const int a;
  const char* const b;
  const bool c;
}

namespace allowed_values {
constexpr Foo first = {1, "asdf", true};
constexpr Foo second = {2, "fdsa", true};
constexpr Foo third = {3, "brrrr", false};
}
```

Is there some nice mechanism, design pattern or a trick in C++ (up to C++17), which allows me to forbid using other values combinations than intended? I.e. in a different source file it behaves as follows:

```
// possible:
auto val1 = allowed_values::first;
// compilation error wanted:
Foo val2{4, "aaa", true};
// compilation error wanted (or at least nice-to-have):
constexpr Foo fourth = {4, "bbb", false};
auto val3 = fourth;
```

Comment: You could put that logic inside the constructor. Or if you expose only one argument in the construtor, and fill in the other members based on that one argument, to enforce this policy.

Comment: It seems like you want an `enum` or an `enum class`, possibly together with a map from a canonical index to the values of the other parameters.

Comment: This sounds like the job for constructors, setters, getters, and private variables.  Objects let you wrap your variables so that you can control what happens to them.

Comment: @NathanPierson actually enums are not restricted to a set of values, what is restricted is only the values that have names, but other values are not forbidden

Comment: Good point. It still seems like it would express the design intention of a class that consists of some finite, pre-written collection of valid values and states.

Comment: @NathanPierson yep, my first idea was enums, too. But taking the question literally they don't help. Could well be that OPs actual problem is fine with enums

Comment: No, I don't think enums would work, at least not alone. Traditional enums can be only integer type, not struct. As for class enum, they can't have underlying real values, like strings or structs, so it is even worse. Perhaps i could have a factory which returns possible structs given available class enum values, though it seems a bit of an overkill to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the constructor private, so no other objects can be created. The objects you want to create must then be created by a friend or the class itself:

```
struct Foo {
  const int a;
  const char* const b;
  const bool c;
private:
    Foo(int a,const char* const b,bool c) : a(a),b(b),c(c) {}
public:
    static Foo first() { return {1, "asdf", true}; }
    static Foo second() { return {2, "fdsa", true};}
    static Foo third() { return {3, "brrrr", false};}
};
```

Comment: You'd probably also want to make all the member variables private with getters if you're going this direction.

Comment: @NathanPierson why, they are const?

Comment: @NathanPierson I didnt want to change more than necessary. If it was my code there were also no `const` members

Comment: @M.A It might be more extensible to make them non-const private with public getters if, for instance, you wanted to support copy and assignment operations when the RHS is in a valid state.

Comment: @NathanPierson, for such a simple POD type, a better abstraction may be to create a `FooBuilder` class that handles the creation and enforcing the invariant, then `Foo` can be an immutable data type.

Comment: This is a nice idea and indeed, then I could return const Foo instead of having const members, which makes it even better. I've also managed to make it constexpr. Thank you all!